# MySQL Routine INSERT Statement with CASE

Tags: mysql, insert

MySQL Routine:

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`%` PROCEDURE `INSERT_Employee_Info`(
IN lname varchar(64),
IN fname varchar(64),
IN mname varchar(64)
)
BEGIN
INSERT INTO tbl_employee_info(lname, fname, mname)
VALUES(lname, fname, mname);
END
```

Sometimes, the values lname, fname and mname may contain nothing but not null, I want the insert statement to insert `NULL` instead of the `''` value.

I had the following in mind but I highly doubt it will work:

```
INSERT INTO tbl_employee_info(lname, fname, mname)
VALUES(CASE lname WHEN '' THEN NULL ELSE lname END,
CASE fname WHEN '' THEN NULL ELSE fname END,
CASE mname WHEN '' THEN NULL ELSE mname END);
```

Comment: What happens when you try it?

Comment: you have an error in your sql syntax

Comment: @paynet because you did not enclosed the `case` statement with parenthesis, see my answer below.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

it will work but you need to put parenthesis around `case`

```
INSERT INTO tbl_employee_info(lname, fname, mname)
VALUES
(
   (CASE lname WHEN '' THEN NULL ELSE lname END),
   (CASE fname WHEN '' THEN NULL ELSE fname END),
   (CASE mname WHEN '' THEN NULL ELSE mname END)
);
```

- [**SQLFiddle Demo** (*added `IF` alternative*)](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a0741/1)

Answer (score 4):

You can use [IF()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_if) function -

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`%` PROCEDURE `INSERT_Employee_Info`(
  IN p_lname varchar(64),
  IN p_fname varchar(64),
  IN p_mname varchar(64)
)
BEGIN    
  INSERT INTO tbl_employee_info(lname, fname, mname)
  VALUES(
    IF(p_lname = '', NULL, p_lname),
    IF(p_fname = '', NULL, p_fname),
    IF(p_mname = '', NULL, p_mname));
END
```

One more suggestion - do not use the same names for field names and parameters.